# ServletContextListener v/s init() method

Tags: servlets, init, servlet-listeners

which better between calling a servlet init method or implementing servlet context listener when we have to set some data on application startup.

Comment: Any reason why you have not accepted the answer below? If you have another answer instead please list it and accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @iX3 below answer doesn't specify which one is better.

Comment: But you said you "got [your] answer" -- I was just asking that you share your findings. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: Well i am using listener but i didn't accept this answer because i needed some more points(answers) for using listeners.

Answer (score 9):

The servlet context listener is made for that. Use it. You could use a servlet, but you would have to make sure it's started at deploy time, and before other servlets. And which one of all your servlets would have this responsibility?

Comment: thanx i got my answer ...any other good reason to use servlet context listener over servlet